# SQL Express client memory usage differs to SQL Enterprise client memory usage

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-express

I am experiencing a big difference in .Net application memory usage using the same app against two copies of the same database.  The only difference is that in scenario 1 I am using a local copy of the database registered to an instance of `SQL Server 2005 Express` - and in scenario 2 I am using a remote copy of the database registered to an instance of `SQL Server 2008 Enterprise`.

To my knowledge, I would only expect a difference in the SQL performance and SQL memory usage (since Express has a 1GB limit).

But - what I see is an enormous difference (1GB) of memory usage between them - i.e. the `SQL Express` scenario using 1GB more of memory mostly.  `SQL Express` also seems to be much slower particularly working with big tables and large queries - but I would expect this memory hit to be in SQL and not on my consuming/client application???

The app connects to SQL server using `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection` and carries out frequent `SqlCommand` and `SqlBulkCopy` operations.

Any helpful thoughts would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Is this a rich client app? All that differs is the connection string?

Comment: Almost, it's a .Net application (not a GUI app, but a service) which connects to SQL.  And yes, the only difference between the two test scenarios is the connection string ...

Comment: How are you measuring the memory usage? Is it consuming loads of memory in one hit or a gradual increase over time?

Comment: Every minute I write the private memory usage to a file.  Over the course of 24 hours it peaks frequently at 150-250Mb in scenario 1 and peaks at the same frequency at 1000Mb in scenario 2.

Comment: You might want to get hold of a profiler (e.g. RedGate Memory profiler) to get some more detail on what is going on

Comment: Yep I've already got ANTS memory profiler running.  It shows a lot of objects from the System.Data lib I am using ...

Comment: Have considered the app uses more memory when not using the local DB simply because it has more memory available (local DB is not using up memory).

Comment: I'd look into the feature differences between SQL 2005 and 2008. Perhaps SQL 2005 had poor support for some operation you're doing and the .Net SQL library is falling back to a less efficient method. I suggest trying this w SQL 2008 Express and see what your memory usage does.

Comment: Maybe the app is using more memory because the server is able to handle a larger load. Have you looked at what happens when the two clients do the same workload at the same rate?

Comment: which platform is used? x32 or x64?

Answer (score 1):

For you second question about slow express on big tables and queries, that is normal because express version is consuming more memory and disk than enterprise version. The Enterprise version is using a feature called Enhanched-Read-ahead and Scan(a.k.a Merry-go-round scans),which has enormous difference in performance of large queries.

For example:

Assume that UserA and UserB both issue the `SELECT * FROM Customer` command, which results in a table scan. UserA issues the command first; UserB issues the command 20 seconds later. The table has 100 million rows (it's a very big table), and the scan is running on a machine that has non Enterprise Edition installed. The table scan for UserA begins reading the Customer table on the first page of the table. Twenty seconds later, the scan for UserB starts reading pages that UserA has already read, even though some of the pages might already have been flushed back out of cache. Sometimes this process creates tremendous disk contention and draws on memory.

The Enterprise Edition performs an Enhanced Read-ahead and Scan a little differently. Unlike with the non Enterprise Edition versions, when UserA issues the `SELECT * FROM Customer` command, the Enterprise Edition begins scanning the Customer table. When UserB issues the same command 20 seconds later, the table scan for UserB starts exactly where UserA is currently reading. UserA and UserB's queries will both read the last page of the Customers table at about the same time, but then UserB's scan will go back to the beginning of the Customer table to scan the pages that UserA had scanned before UserB began its query. This process dramatically reduces disk contention and the draw on memory.

Comment: The key point here is that enterprise will "eat" all memory unless you specify a max size in the config.  The product assumes it is the only application running on a server and configures itself appropriately

Comment: Yes,but another key point for large tables is enterprise feature called marry-go-round(as explained in answer :) )!

Comment: Which has nothing to do with the OP's question.

Comment: There are way to much differences. Also most likely the local instance will use shared memory over tcp ip. But the main point has already been discussed here.